# Formatting Text Output Java SE

Tags: java

I am trying to print some ASCII art from a **System.out.println** in Java. When I do this though all the spacing in place in the source code goes away. What is printed out is a mess of nonsense that does not make any sense. Figure 1 shows what the source code looks like and what the ASCII art should look like. Figure 2 shows what the banner actually looks like when the program is run.

My question is how can I print the ASCII art as expected? **How can I print the ASCII art with the formatting that makes the banner readable?**

For instance with Python I could easily have this work by using triple quotes. Does Java have a similar text mechanism?

[image: Figure 1: How the ASCII Art should look, how it is in the source code.]
*Figure 1*: What the ASCII art should look like

[image]
*Figure 2*: What the ASCII art looks like when the program is run

Please see my source code as follows:

```
package Boring;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class EnchantedBoringLevel {


    public EnchantedBoringLevel () {
        System.out.println("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n");
    /*  System.out.println("\n" + 
"EEEE           h              t         d     BBBB                          FFFF                  t  " +
"E              h              t         d     B   B         ii              F                     t  " +
"EEE  nnn   ccc hhh   aa nnn  ttt eee  ddd     BBBB  ooo rrr    nnn  ggg     FFF  ooo rrr eee  ss ttt " +
"E    n  n c    h  h a a n  n  t  e e d  d     B   B o o r   ii n  n g g     F    o o r   e e  s   t  " +
"EEEE n  n  ccc h  h aaa n  n  tt ee   ddd     BBBB  ooo r   ii n  n ggg     F    ooo r   ee  ss   tt " +
"                                                                      g                              " +
"                                                                     ggg                             " 
);
*/
        System.out.println("***Enchanted Boring Forest***");
        System.out.println("Welcome to another boring level of this video game!\n\n\n\n");
        this.enchant();
    }

    public void enchant() {

        System.out.println("You find yourself in a magical forest all alone.\nYou hear music in the distance.\n" +
        "An elf appears and takes you to their tree house mansion.");

        System.out.print("The elf prince offers you three choices 1) invisible ring, 2) galactic sunglasses, 3) a map of the enchanted forest. Which do you choose?");
        Scanner enchanted_choice = new Scanner(System.in);
        String choice;
        choice = enchanted_choice.next();

        switch(new Integer(choice)) {

            case 1:
                System.out.println("You chose the invisible ring");
                new BoringInvisibleRing();
                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.println("You chose the galactic sunglasses");
                new BoringGalacticSunglasses();
                break;
            case 3:
                System.out.println("You chose the map of the enchanted forest");
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("You shot yourself in the face.");

        }
    }





}
```

Comment: Ah, excellent point. I have added my source code with the ASCII art in comments.

Answer (score 1):

Console wraps your text. Set heigher column number in console settings

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that java treats your text as a single line and cmd wraps it, so it becomes unreadable. To make a new line, use the newline character `\n`.